# Is it possible to use ConfidentialClientApp in Console App?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-msal

Is it possible to use a Confidential Client Application as part of a Console App in Visual Studio?  I've been trying to do that, but when I to call a method using the `IConfidentialClientApplication` class I just built, I get the following error:

```
AADSTS53000: Device is not in required device state: compliant. Conditional Access policy 
requires a compliant device, and the device is not compliant.
```

I've been trying to figure out what this means in my case.  My machine is, in fact, compliant (and I have so far tried this out on two separate, compliant machines).  I'm starting to think that given the description of Confidential Client Application found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-client-applications, which states that Confidential Client Application's are, e.g., web apps on their own server, it isn't possible to use the `ConfidentialClientApplication` class effectively in a Console App through Visual Studio.  Is this right?  The error is a little bit hard to decipher, since it seems to suggest that my physical computer is the problem (but I don't think that is the case, here).

Edit: I thought I could code this up in Visual Studio Console App as a lightweight proof-of-concept, but maybe I need to spin up a server if I want to test this out fully.

Comment: Is there any update about this issue? Does Gary Archer's answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

A console app is a public client if you are triggering user authentication. You then use the loopback flow from [RFC8252](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252#section-7.3) as in [this example C# code](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples/tree/main/NetCoreConsoleClient/src/NetCoreConsoleClient).

A daemon process on a backend server is another type of console app - with a hidden console window. These can be a confidential client and would use the client credentials flow, with a client secret. Sounds like this is not your use case though.